# Problem with passing a var from mounted to computed in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, uislider

I tried to pass a variable from mounted. I get them from api request => `sliderAmount`, and pass them to computed. But I have an error "sliderAmount is not defined"

Should I first set var in `data` and then connecting between mouted and computed?

HTML

```
         .box_slider 
                  VueSlideBar(v-model="value"
                  :min="1"
                  :max="sliderAmountMap"
                  :processStyle="slider.processStyle"
                  :lineHeight="slider.lineHeight"
                  :tooltipStyles="{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderColor: 
                      'red' }"
                  class="demo-demo" id="slider-1")
```

Vue.js

```
import co from "@/util/co.js";
import VueSlideBar from "vue-slide-bar";
export default {
  name: "Repaid",
  components: {
   VueSlideBar
  },
  data() {
   return {
     value: 8,
     slider: {
       lineHeight: 10
     },
     sliderAmount: undefined
   };
 },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
    co.getLoanPriceList().then(data => {
      let dataLoan = data.data;
      console.log(dataLoan);
      let sliderAmount = dataLoan.amounts; //this is my var which I want 
      to pass to computed
      console.log(sliderAmount);//here I have an array: [400, 600, 800, 1000, 
      1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2500, 3000]
    });
  },
  computed: {
     sliderAmountMap() {
      const sliderAmountValue = this.sliderAmount; 
       console.log(this.sliderAmount); //here I have undefined
    }
 }
```

};

I want to pass a value from sliderAmountMap (which is an array: [400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2500, 3000]) to my max in component VueSlideBar. But still have an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a value declared inside execution context. Garbage collector clears all related `fn` memory allocations once the `fn` execution context get over (Unless you are making closure).

To solve the problem - Either

**Add `sliderAmount` to `data` property and change it**

```
import co from "@/util/co.js";
import VueSlideBar from "vue-slide-bar";
export default {
  name: "Repaid",
  components: {
   VueSlideBar
  },
  data() {
   return {
     value: 8,
     slider: {
       lineHeight: 10
     },
     sliderAmount: undefined
   };
 },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
    co.getLoanPriceList().then(data => {
      let dataLoan = data.data;
      console.log(dataLoan);
      this.sliderAmount = dataLoan.amounts; //this is my var which I want 
      to pass to computed
      console.log(this.sliderAmount.length);
    });
  },
  computed: {
     sliderAmountMap() {
      const sliderAmountValue = this.sliderAmount.length; 
       return sliderAmountValue;
    }
 }
```

Or

**Declare global variable.**

```
import co from "@/util/co.js";
import VueSlideBar from "vue-slide-bar";
var sliderAmount;

export default {
  name: "Repaid",
  components: {
   VueSlideBar
  },
  data() {
   return {
     value: 8,
     slider: {
       lineHeight: 10
     },
   };
 },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
    co.getLoanPriceList().then(data => {
      let dataLoan = data.data;
      console.log(dataLoan);
      sliderAmount = dataLoan.amounts; //this is my var which I want 
      to pass to computed
      console.log(sliderAmount.length);
    });
  },
  computed: {
     sliderAmountMap() {
      const sliderAmountValue = sliderAmount.length; 
       return sliderAmountValue;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I changed this var declare adding property to data, but now when I do `console.log(sliderAmountValue)` it is undefined. So my value from sliderAmount from mounted didn't pass?

Comment: When you add a property to `data` it get added to `vue` context which is `this`. Try logging `console.log(this.sliderAmount)`.

Comment: I did, but I still have undefined. But when I `console.log(sliderAmount)` in mounted I have correct value.

Comment: update you changes in question and let me see what you have done

Comment: I did and added coments.

Comment: You are creating a local variable and again it will not get accessed. Update `let sliderAmount = dataLoan.amounts;` to `this.sliderAmount = dataLoan.amounts;` in your `mounted` hook

Comment: Yeaaaa.. Ok. now I understand! My big mistake. I tried to change var only in computed, but it is obvious, that I should in mounted as well. Thanks for help. Now I have it.